# DocuSign Document URL

Tags: docusignapi

Once the customer signs the document electronically I want to save the link to the signed document. How can I get the url to the DocuSign document once we  create the envelope. I did find that https://docusign.net/Member/EmailStart.aspx?m= is one way but is not a secure connection. I also see on creating an envelope there is a return URI, can I use that to find the url to the document?

Answer (score 1):

It's not technically possible to "save a (direct) link to a DocuSign document".  What you can do, however, is have a link/button within your application that, *onClick*, will execute a DocuSign REST API call to retrieve an envelope's documents, and then read the response and write the byte stream to the browser (thus displaying the documents to the user).

The DocuSign REST API call to retrieve all documents (combined into a single file) for the specified envelope is simply:

```
GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/documents/combined
```

You can optionally add the ***certificate*** querystring parameter (set to either ***true*** or ***false***) to indicate whether or not you want the response to also contain the "Certificate of Completion" for the Envelope.  See pages 131-132 of the DocuSign REST API guide (https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) for more detailed info about this API call.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any option to save document directly. You need to make API call to retrieve byte stream for that document/envelope and need to save it manually.